# Y-axis on large negative and small positive values in High Charts

Tags: angular, charts, highcharts, angular2-highcharts

At first my data serie values is completely dynamic it can contain any range of values so `tickAmounts` or `tickInterval` doesn't work out for me and also adding multiple y-axis for single data series didn't help.
In my scenario issue occurred when there is some small positive values relative to large negative value so the `tickInterval` for y-axis is so large that small positive value does't appear on chart I have to zoom it to see values.

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ideazgeni/cg3qhfap/) link to see issue in details

Here is sample dataSerie

```
series: [{
        name: 'Series 1',
        data: [-348957349855, 23984323, 2938234, 7823479, 2293023]
    }]
```

Is there any solution to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

A solution could be to use a different yAxis type. The [API](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.type) show an example with negative logarithmic value. For your example :

```
yAxis: {
    type:'logarithmic',
    title: {
        text: 'Values'
    }
},
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8kuh12bn/)

**Edit : For Angular integration**

*nb : I'm not an Angular user, maybe this will not work*

**main.ts**

```
...
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';

// Now add the function
(function (H) {
    // Pass error messages
    H.Axis.prototype.allowNegativeLog = true;

    // Override conversions
    H.Axis.prototype.log2lin = function (num) {
        var isNegative = num < 0,
            adjustedNum = Math.abs(num),
            result;
        if (adjustedNum < 10) {
            adjustedNum += (10 - adjustedNum) / 10;
        }
        result = Math.log(adjustedNum) / Math.LN10;
        return isNegative ? -result : result;
    };
    H.Axis.prototype.lin2log = function (num) {
        var isNegative = num < 0,
            absNum = Math.abs(num),
            result = Math.pow(10, absNum);
        if (result < 10) {
            result = (10 * (result - 1)) / (10 - 1);
        }
        return isNegative ? -result : result;
    };
}(Highcharts));
...
```

Comment: your solutions is great and working in JSfiddle but I having issue while integrating this in my Angular 6 project, I am currently using `highcharts-angular` wrapper, i am adding the function in `ngOnInit` or `constructor`

Comment: bundle of thanks bro u guide me right direction, I will try it in angular-6(TS)

Comment: I prepared you an online demo of this solution in Angular app with `highcharts-angular` official wrapper: https://codesandbox.io/s/xp63v0o7rw. Check also the docs about loading your custom wrappers: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular#to-load-a-wrapper.

Comment: I did the same above and receiving 

- Property 'allowNegativeLog' does not exist on type 'Axis'
- Property 'lin2log' does not exist on type 'Axis'